# Declaring temporary variables from vector<vector<string>> in a for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, temporary-objects, dangling-pointer

I am trying to declare temporary variables in a sequence of for-loops. To do that, I use a range-based loop for each "vector container" (i.e. `vector<vector<string> > containerXYZ`) and declare temporary variables within each for-loop.

Here's part of my code to give you an idea of the for-loops:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

//Global variables
string i {};                                            
string j {};

class CSVReader
{
...
  vector<vector<string> > getData1();
  vector<vector<string> > getData2();
  vector<vector<string> > getData3();
}

vector<vector<string> > CSVReader::getData1()
{...};
vector<vector<string> > CSVReader::getData2()
{...};
vector<vector<string> > CSVReader::getData3()
{...};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  vector<vector<string> > Container1 = reader.getData1;  //reads data from file1
  vector<vector<string> > Container2 = reader.getData2;  //reads data from file2

  //-----FIRST LOOP....
  for(vector<string> vecOfContainer1 : Container1)
  {
    i = vecOfContainer1[0];  //Declaring temporary variables used for container3 in my vector-function
    j = vecOfContainer1[1];

    vector<vector<string> > Container3 = reader.getData3();  //reads data from file1

      //-----SECOND LOOP....
      for(vector<string> vecOfContainer2 : Container2)
      {
        string var1_str = vecOfContainer2[2];  //Temporary variables which probably cause the error...
        string var2_str = vecOfContainer2[3];

        float var1 = stof(var1_str);
        float var2 = stof(var2_str);

        //Do calculations...

      };
    };
    return 0;
  }
```

My problem now is that the code is built correctly, but while running, it terminates before finishing my loops and giving a logical error in my output:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
              Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

RUN FAILED (exit value 3, total time: 3s)
```

After some research I assume that "dangling reference" is the keyword to my problem. However, since my declaration of variables worked well in my first loop, it doesn't in the second loop. Here's where I would like to ask for help!?

Let me know if you require the whole code. I thought this would be sufficient for discussion though...

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to use the debugger properly. The build is succesful, but when the debug window opens, it stops right there...

Comment: Really then, do start learning it, it will pay off. Use Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you have two nested `for` loops? It would make sense to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the real size of all of your temporary variables beforehand, but access them without any checks with `vecOfContainer1[0]` etc.

You should use `vecOfContainer1.at(0)` which gives you at least an `std::out_of_range` exception which should provide you more details.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The error says now:
`what(): vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 10) >= this->size() (which is 1)`
Note: I use different elements as stated in my code example. The vector size should be large enough though. When I print the containers, all of them have the elements as expected!

Comment: The exception says you are accessing the vector at position 10, while the vector has only the size 1. The debugger should stop  right there, where the exception occurs (maybe you have to go back in the stack trace) and then you should see what values all your variables currently have.

Comment: Ok, this is what I expected. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my complete code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

//Global variables
string line {};
string i {};                                            
string j {};                                           



/*
 * CSV Reader class to open CSV file which is further parsed  
 * in vector containers
 */
class CSVReader
{
    string fileName, delimiter;
public:
    CSVReader(string filename, string delm = ";") :
        fileName(filename), delimiter(delm)
    {}
    vector<vector<string> > getContainer1();                                            //Function to fetch unique objects from CSV file
    vector<vector<string> > getContainer3();                                            //Fetch all corresponding lines to object_i,j
};

class CSVXReader
{
    string fileName, delimiter;
public:
    CSVXReader(string filename, string delm = ",") :                                    //Notice comma delimiter for CSVX file, instead of semicolon for CSVReader
        fileName(filename), delimiter(delm)
    {}

    vector<vector<string> > getContainer2();                                            //Fetch data from CSVX file
};

/*
 * Boolean function template to search for a string in vector and return "true"
 * Use it as: if(Contains(vector,item)){do...}  :if vector contains "item", do...
 */
template <typename T> 
const bool Contains( vector<T>& Vec, const T& Element) 
{
    if (std::find(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), Element) != Vec.end())
        return true;

    return false;
};

/*
 * Parse through CSV file line by line 
 * and return the data in vector of vector
 * of strings
 */
vector<vector<string> > CSVReader::getContainer1()
{
    ifstream file(fileName);
    
    vector<vector<string> > Container1;                                                 //Vector of vector contains all unique objects_i,j with constants 

    while (getline(file, line))                                                         //Iterate through each line and split the content using delimiter
    {
    
        vector<string> vecOfContainer1;                                                 //Vector contains a row from CSV file
        boost::algorithm::split(vecOfContainer1, line, boost::is_any_of(delimiter));    //Vector content is delimited 
    
        i = vecOfContainer1.at(2);                                                      //Here: object No., e.g. 1_380
        j = vecOfContainer1.at(3);                                                      //hotspot = 1,2,...,10   i.e. element j of object_i
        int a = 0;                                                                      //Integer variable, used in following if-loop to validate whether 'object' & 'hotspot'
                                                                                    //appear for the first time or not 
    
        /*
         * Creating a vector containing only necessary constants of the
         * corresponding line to copy into 'Container1'
         */
        vector<string> constantsOfVec;
        constantsOfVec = vecOfContainer1;                                      
        constantsOfVec.erase(constantsOfVec.begin()+11,constantsOfVec.begin()+21);      //Deleting unnecessary elements of vecOfContainer1
        constantsOfVec.erase(constantsOfVec.begin()+4,constantsOfVec.begin()+8);
    
    
        /*
         * Searching whether 'object' i & 'hotspot' j exists in the whole 'Container1' already.
         * If it exists, a=>1, and at next if-function the current vector (i.e. line) is not added to 'Container1'
         * else, a=>0, and current vector is added! 
         */
     
        for(vector<string> constantsOfVec : Container1)                                 //Browsing through all vectors of 'Container1'
        {
            if(Contains(constantsOfVec, i) && Contains(constantsOfVec, j))              //Browsing through a vector (i.e. line) and searching for 'detail' i (e.g. 1_380) & hotspot j
            {
                    a = 1;
            }
        }
        if(a != 1)                                                                      //Line (or vector) is added to 'Container1' container if i&j appear for the first time
        {
            Container1.push_back(constantsOfVec);
        }
    }
    Container1.erase(Container1.begin());                                               //Deletes first line of CSV file, i.e. column header

    file.close();
    return Container1;    
};

vector<vector<string> > CSVReader::getContainer3()
{
    ifstream file(fileName);
   
    vector<vector<string> > Container3;                                                 //Vector of vector contains all lines of object_i,j
   
    while (getline(file, line))                                                         //Iterate through each line and split the content using delimiter
    {      
        vector<string> vecOfContainer1;                                                 //Vector contains a row from RAO file
        boost::algorithm::split(vecOfContainer1, line, boost::is_any_of(delimiter));    //Vector content is delimited 
 
        /*
         * Creating a vector containing only necessary elements of the
         * corresponding line to copy into 'Container3' container
         */
        vector<string> parameterOfVec;
        parameterOfVec = vecOfContainer1;                                      
        parameterOfVec.erase(parameterOfVec.begin()+21,parameterOfVec.end());   
        parameterOfVec.erase(parameterOfVec.begin()+8,parameterOfVec.begin()+12);
        parameterOfVec.erase(parameterOfVec.begin()+4,parameterOfVec.begin()+7);
        parameterOfVec.erase(parameterOfVec.begin(),parameterOfVec.begin()+2);

        if(Contains(parameterOfVec, i) && Contains(parameterOfVec, j))                  //Browsing through a vector (i.e. line) and searching for detail i and hotspot j of corresponding loop
        {
            Container3.push_back(parameterOfVec);
        };   
    };

    file.close();
    return Container3;
};

vector<vector<string> > CSVXReader::getContainer2()
{
    ifstream file(fileName);

    vector<vector<string> > Container2;

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        vector<string> vecOfContainer2;
        boost::algorithm::split(vecOfContainer2, line, boost::is_any_of(delimiter));

        Container2.push_back(vecOfContainer2);

    };

    Container2.erase(Container2.begin());                                               //Deletes first line of CSVX file, i.e. column header

    file.close();
    return Container2;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    CSVReader readerCSV("CSV_Example_.csv");                                    //Creating an object of CSVReader to open CSV file
    CSVXReader readerCSVX("CSVX_Example.csvx");                                 //Creating an object of CSVXReader to open CSVX file

    vector<vector<string> > Container1 = readerCSV.getContainer1();                     //Read data from CSV file and insert all unique objects (i,j) in 'Container1'
    vector<vector<string> > Container2 = readerCSVX.getContainer2();
 
    
////------------------------------FIRST LOOP FOR OBJECT i, HOTSPOT j---------------------------------------------------------------------////

    for(vector<string> constantsOfVec : Container1)                                     //Iterating through 'Container1'
    {           
    
        i = constantsOfVec.at(2);                                                       //Declare Object No. and Hotspot of the current loop to be used 
        j = constantsOfVec.at(3);                                                       //in 'Container3' for inserting all vectors with exact same i&j in while-loop
    
        vector<vector<string> > Container3 = readerCSV.getContainer3();                         //Read data from CSV file and insert all lines with corresponding i&j in 'Container3' container
    
    
////------------------------------SECOND LOOP FOR TIME k---------------------------------------------------------------------------------////
    
        for(vector<string> vecOfContainer2 : Container2)                                //Iterating through 'Container2', i.e. time k
        {
      
            string var1_str = vecOfContainer2.at(10);
            string var2_str = vecOfContainer2.at(12);
            string var3_str = vecOfContainer2.at(16);
      
        //Converting strings of 'Container3' to floats with std::stof('string')
            float var1 = stof(var1_str);                                      
            float var2 = stof(var2_str);
            float var3 = stof(var3_str);
        
        //get parameterOfVec(var1,var2,var3)_ij for time k, i.e. find line in Container3 with closest parameters to current line of Container2
            
        };
     
      
    };   
    return 0;
}
```

I nested my loops, because I want to create my Container3 while I am looping through Container 1, say, `push_back` all lines of file1, which belong to object_i,j.
In the second loop, I am browsing through another file2 and have to find for each line of Container2 (file2) the corresponding line in Container3 (file1). This has to repeat for all objects_ij, i.e. all lines of Container1 (file1).
That's why I create Container2 in the beginning, in order to access it for each object_ij. And Container3 is a temporary container corresponding to each object_ij from my understanding.